# I guess some Ruby internals

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, self

```
class MyClass

  def instance_variable=(var)
    puts "inside getter"
    instance_variable = var
  end

  def function_1
    self.instance_variable = "whatever"
  end

  def function_2
    @instance_variable = "whatever"
  end

end



myclass = MyClass.new

myclass.function1
```

results wiht "inside getter" on the console

`myclass.function2`

does not.

Im new to Ruby, do not know the difference, couldnt find it on the web...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I assumed that by appending the "=", I overwrite a getter method for an implicitly defined instance variable "instance_variable."

That's also the reason why I called it that way.

Im not used to be allowed to use "=" in function names.

Thats why I assumed it would had some special meaning.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT2:

I just thought I really overwrite the assignment and not only the getter. I got it all mixed up.

Sorry and Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have (misleading) named your setter `instance_variable`.  It is not an instance variable, it is a method that sets an instance variable.

When you call `self.instance_variable=` you are calling that method.  When you set `@instance_variable` directly you are setting the variable itself, and that is why the setter method is not called.

A more idiomatic naming convention would be something like:

```
def name=(value)
  @name = value
end
```

Of course, for simply, pass-through type getters and setters you can use

```
attr_reader :name #generates getter only
attr_writer :name #generates setter only, not very common
attr_accessor :name #generates getter and setter
```

The above methods are syntactic sugar which generate the get and/or set methods for you.  They can be overriden later to provide additional functionality if needed.

---

EDIT: I see that you have made an update and just wanted to point out that this method doesn't set an instance variable at all:

```
def instance_variable=(var)
  puts "inside getter"
  instance_variable = var
end
```

In this case `instance_variable` is simply a local variable and will be discarded as soon as the method exits.  Local variables take precedence over instance methods, and instance variables always begin with a `@` symbol.

Comment: But ruby does not do that for you at all unless you use the attr_xxx syntax that I show in my answer.

Comment: What I wanted was an instance variable.

There is no way to define it explicitely, thats why I called the method itself "instance_variable=".

What I assumed was, that appending the "=" sign makes it THE getter for the instance variable "instance_variable". Like overwriting it.

But now I think, "=" does not do that. 
Its just a character? Like "a-Z"?

Comment: @krzysiek: *"There is no way to define it explicitely"* - I'm not sure what you mean by that.  You can certainly define an instance variable, you simply declare and initialize it, i.e., `@some_instance_var = 1`.  The `=` at the end of a method would make it a setter, not a getter, and it does have meaning. It means that you can use it like `my_property = 1`, i.e., it looks like assigning a field, but in actuality you are calling the `my_property=(value)` method.

Comment: well... thats what I read on the web... one does not defines the instance_variables explicitely like "@some_instance_var = 1" but ONLY implicitely by defining setter and getter methods like (def instance_var(value)/ @instance_var = value/ end /def instance_var/ @instance_var/end). Like because Ruby is dynamic or something.

Comment: @krzysiek: No, that's not true.  You can define instance variables just as well, and if they are a part of the internal implementation of a class as opposed to the public interface that is exactly how they should be defined.